# Node.js app stops taking requests after a 2~ hours

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple app using Express.js that handles posted data from remote systems.

There is basic authentication (express.basicAuth) and a handful of other modules (generic-pool for DB connection pooling, moment.js for time calculations, and mysql) as well as Forever to run the app as a service. The app is running on SuSe 11.2 in case that matters.

Everything runs perfectly fine for approximately 2 hours - data is posted, processed, then stored. Roughly 1kb~ of data per post, 80 posts per hour. After that the app becomes unresponsive until the app is restarted ($ forever restart)

I'm quite new to Node and don't know where to go next to debug the problem. Nothing is being written to the access or error log files when the app goes unresponsive, and not sure if there is another way to get meaningful output or a stack trace.

Any advice or direction would be appreciated!

Edit:
As added in the comments, the data is parsed and written directly to a MySQL table using generic-pool for the connection management.

Specifically:

```
var poolModule = require('generic-pool');
var pool = poolModule.Pool({
    name: 'mysql',
    create: function(cb) {
        var mysql = require('mysql');
        var db = mysql.createConnection({ host: '...', user: '...', 'password: '...' });
        cb(null, db);
    },
    destroy: function(client) { client.end(); },
    max: 10
});
```

Then in the router:

```
function(req, res) {
    pool.acquire(function(err,client)) {
        if(err) throw err;

        // ...data parsing / query building


        client.query('...the query...', function(err, rows, fields) {
            pool.release(client);
            if(err) { res.send(err); }
            else { res.send('success'); }
        }
    });
}
```

Edit2 - it looks like a failure event is occurring which results in the db connection not closing. I noticed 2 connections open for 5 and 15 minutes.. given this rate of growth the max connection limit (10) could easily be reached and cause the hanging.
I'll know soon enough if this is the culprit! :)

Comment: What do you mean by unresponsive and how are you storing this data that you're receiving. We run a live site with Node/Express and I've not seen anything close to this behaviour before.

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak. Can you profile your app?

Comment: @raina77ow I was thinking the same thing, if you're using memory for storage you should swap to a DB and if you're using a DB make sure you're properly cleaning up the connection.

Comment: The data is being parsed then written directly into a MySQL table. With generic-pool it is a matter of "acquire" to add the connection to the pool and execute the query, then on callback running "release" to add the connection back into the pool for cleanup.

Answer (score 4):

The DB connection wasn't being released when an error was encountered. When the connection limit was reached eventually reached subsequent page requests hung. After improving the data processing and error handling the problem went away.

Comment: Could you say a little bit more about how you improved data processing? I'm having the same problem. But, I've been sure to add release statements to every err handle and I'm still running into trouble after many queries.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to maintain your db connection like below?

```
setInterval(function(){
    // Run query to retain db connection
    db.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
}, 60 * 1000);
```